# How do I detect whether or not the screen on an android device is a touchscreen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, ontouchlistener

I'm writting an app Screenserver not using dayDream.

ScreenSaverActivity I override ontouch:

```
@Override   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+ 10*1000;

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

        this.onBackPressed(); // turn off app
        return false;   }
```

AlrmService.class

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("edu.com.screensaver", "edu.com.screensaver.ScreenSaverActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i); // turn on again
    }

}
```

I want update time for alrmActivity so I added  MyService.class handle touch event

```
public class MyService extends Service implements OnTouchListener{
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyService click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            Log.i(TAG, "Action :" + event.getAction() + "\t X :" + event.getRawX() + "\t Y :"+ event.getRawY());

        return true;
    }
}
```

"MyService click" message is never call. When i touch in main activity after 10 seconds the app open again.

Any solution is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: A Service has no UI, and therefore does not receive touch event callbacks from the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

boolean isTouchSupported = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.touchscreen");